# Why does GitHub pages now show a 404 error?

Tags: github

Thanks for taking the time to read my first question.

I created an hosted a repo on GitHub assigned it to my name and committed and yesterday I could see the website.

Today it seems to have gone offline with no error and with no other change.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Site:  mylokaye.github.io
Domain: mylokaye.tech

Error:

404

There isn't a GitHub Pages site here.

If you're trying to publish one, read the full documentation to learn how to set up GitHub Pages for your repository, organization, or user account.

GitHub Status — @githubstatus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

One possible solution is to ensure there is a file called CNAME on the branch your GitHub Pages site is served from, containing your custom domain name.

### Root cause

When you configure a custom domain in the repo's Pages settings, GitHub generates a CNAME file and commits this to the branch or folder the site is being served from. If this file is removed, you will see a 404 page instead of your site and the custom domain configuration will be blank again.

If you are using something like Docusaurus then when a content change is made and the static site is rebuilt, the CNAME file was being wiped out.

Viewing the commit history for the branch my site was being served from (`gh-pages`) I saw commits which added a CNAME file to the repo root corresponding to when I configured the custom domain in the repo's Pages settings.

[image: Commit history from gh-pages branch]

In the screenshot above, the commit on 2nd Jan was generated by GitHub automatically when I configured the custom domain. The commit on 3rd Jan was Docusaurus publishing a content change, which removed the CNAME file and my site returned a 404 on the custom domain url. Same thing happened on 5th Jan when I reconfigured the site and then made a content change and the GitHub Action publishing my site generated the deploy commit which removed the CNAME file again.

### Fix for Docusaurus v2

My site is generated by <Docusaurus.io> and I'd missed [this](https://docusaurus.io/docs/deployment#github-pages-overview) in the documentation where it says to create a static file in the `/static` folder which will be copied over to the published branch. The file contents should be a single line of text with the custom domain name eg. `buildthethingright.com`

[image: CNAME static file for Docusaurus v2 site]

For other site generators there will probably be different ways to ensure a CNAME file with a custom domain remains on the GitHub Pages branch. Note there was a different process for Docusaurus v1, so check your static site generator docs for how to do this for you.

Answer (score -1):

The typical trigger for an error 404 message is when website content has been removed or moved to another URL. There are also other reasons why an error message could appear. These include:

The URL or its content (such as files or images) was either deleted or moved (without adjusting any internal links accordingly)
The URL was written incorrectly (during the creation process or a redesign), linked incorrectly, or typed into the browser incorrectly
The server responsible for the website is not running or the connection is broken
The requested domain name can’t be converted to an IP by the domain name system (DNS)
The entered domain name doesn’t exist (anymore)

Check this web-site -> https://www.pleth.com/posts/200-301-404-other-numbers-http-error-codes

Answer (score -2):

The typical trigger for an error 404 message is when website content has been removed or moved to another URL. There are also other reasons why an error message could appear. These include:

> The URL or its content (such as files or images) was either deleted or moved (without adjusting any internal links accordingly).

> The URL was written incorrectly (during the creation process or a redesign), linked incorrectly, or typed into the browser incorrectly.

> The server responsible for the website is not running or the connection is broken.

> The requested domain name can’t be converted to an IP by the domain name system (DNS).
>
> The entered domain name doesn’t exist (anymore).

Check this website, if you want more answer:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404#Soft_404